# Downloading an XML file on an iPhone, storing it and then using it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, libxml2

I am currently coding an application that is using an XML document to retrieve data (I am using libxml2.2.7.3). I set it to load a local XML-file (in the project in xCode, so along with all the other project files). I found that I wanted to be able to edit this XML file and then have instant updates on the application. I fetch the data from the XML document like this:

```
NSArray *dagensRetList = [self getAllItems:@"//dagensret" fileName:@"dagensret.xml"];
```

I thought that the easiest way to come around this would be to download the xml-file whenever there is a new version of that document available from the webserver that I provide (on every application launch / clicking the refresh button it would download the new file from the server - maybe let it check whether they have the same  tag (weekNumber, it's a Danish coded application))

So I am thinking on what would be the most convenient way to download the file and should I keep this way of fetching the data or would it be more wise to keep the document on the server and they would then read directly from the server everytime? (It could however end up using a lot of traffic, but it's a product for my school so the user-base would be around 1200, but less as not everyone is using a smartphone)

How would you download a file from a webserver and then keep it cached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely cache the file on the device in case the user can't connect to the server.

Something like this should get you started:

```
// Create a URL Request and set the URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Display the network activity indicator
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

// Perform the request on a new thread so we don't block the UI
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Download queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    NSError* err = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse* rsp = nil;

    // Perform the request synchronously on this thread
    NSData *rspData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&rsp error:&err];

    // Once a response is received, handle it on the main thread in case we do any UI updates
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Hide the network activity indicator
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        if (rspData == nil || (err != nil && [err code] != noErr)) {
            // If there was a no data received, or an error...
        } else {
            // Cache the file in the cache directory
            NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString* path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"init.xml"];

            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

            // Do whatever else you want with the data...
        }
    });
});
```